# whats the difference between trap("INT") and rescue Interrupt in ruby script

Tags: ruby

I want to know how trap("INT") is different from rescue Interrupt in ruby. In what circumstances one has to use trap("INT") and in what circumstances one has to use rescue Interrupt.

Also, I have used trap("INT") in my code, but when I call kill -2 , the trap handler is not getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Trap is more like a GOTO jump.

If you rescue Interrupt, you still have your local scope + variables and can do some cleanup for that particular block.

Comment: Thanks kimmmo. But can I use trap and rescue interchangeably without any impact to my code?